# Trigger Coverage sufficient in Sandbox, but 0 when validating

Tags: trigger, unit-test

In our org, we have a custom field on all contacts (Called Custom_Field__c in this post), and I am writing a trigger that will send out an email listing each employee's data in this field whenever an employee's data is changed. In a recently refreshed partial copy sandbox, I am getting sufficient coverage (at least 60% coverage), but when I validate in production I get 0%. I don't think a flow is breaking my trigger, as it works in a partial copy sandbox. The "EmailService" is deployed to production already. Here is my trigger code and unit test code:

Trigger:

```
trigger CustomFieldTrigger on Contact (after update, after insert) {
    Boolean updateNeeded = false;

    Map<ID,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rt_Map = Contact.sObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosById();

    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Contact cont : Trigger.new) {
            Contact old = Trigger.oldMap.get(cont.Id);
            if (rt_map.get(cont.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Employee')) {
                if (old.Custom_Field__c != cont.Custom_Field__c) {
                    updateNeeded = true;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (Trigger.isInsert) {
        for (Contact cont : Trigger.new) {
            if (rt_map.get(cont.recordTypeID).getName().containsIgnoreCase('Employee')) {
                if (cont.Custom_Field__c != '') {
                    updateNeeded = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (updateNeeded) {
        String emailBody = CustomFieldService.getFieldSummary();
        EmailService.SendEmail(emailBody, 'Custom Field Summary Update');

    }
}
```

Unit tests:

```
@isTest
private class CustomFieldTriggerTests {

    @isTest static void testUpdateContact() {
        Account acct = createAccount();
        insert acct;

        Contact cont = createContact(acct.Id);
        insert cont;

        cont.Custom_Field__c = 'Dislikes Failures.';

        Test.startTest();
        update cont;
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertNotEquals(cont.Custom_Field__c, null);
    }

    @isTest
    private static void testInsertContact() {
        Account acct = createAccount();
        insert acct;

        Contact cont = createContact(acct.Id);
        cont.Custom_Field__c = 'Prefers passing unit tests.';
        Test.startTest();
        insert cont;
        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertNotEquals(cont.Custom_Field__c, null);        
    }

    private static Contact createContact(Id accountId) {
        return new Contact(FirstName = 'Unit', 
            LastName = 'Test',
            Custom_Field__c = 'Dislikes failure.',
            AccountId = accountId);
    }

    private static Account createAccount() {
        return new Account( Name = 'Unit Tests R Us' );
    }

}
```

I know the tests don't cover all code, but they cover more enough to deploy. Any reason why I get 0% coverage in production?

Comment: did you deploy the test class?

Comment: Are you deploying a flow that initiated things? If so flows are deployed inactive. You need to do two change sets and activate the flow first. Oh and 60% is not adequate. Especially if you are not testing behavior as even 100% would not be adequate

Comment: I deployed both the test class and the trigger, and that was all I deployed. I am confused as to what you mean about coverage, all triggers in production require at least 1% coverage.